# I have given this url "Group=1&Group=2&Group=3&Group=4", in this I have to remove Group Fields and then pass 1,2,3,4 values inside list using C#?

Tags: c#, url

```
var qs = "Group=1&Group=2&Group=3&Group=4";
string[] keys = new string[] { "Group" };

foreach (string key in keys)
    qs.Remove(key);

foreach (var s in param1)
{
    Console.WriteLine(s);
}
```

Comment: You know ASP.NET will do this for you, right? With Model Binding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This:

```
var qs = "Group=1&Group=2&Group=3&Group=4";
foreach (var value in qs.Split('&').Select(x => x.Split('=')[1]))
{
    Console.WriteLine(value);
}
```

Gives me this:

```
1
2
3
4
```